# TeamCity is not retrieving all files from SubVersion

Tags: svn, teamcity

I'm in the process of setting up a QA server using TeamCity. I've just added a project and its configuration to TeamCity, but have noticed that it's not getting all the files from one of the VCS roots I have set up.

Other projects are not having this problem, and neither is this projects failing to retrieve any files at all from the root in question. It is a small number of DLL files in the /website/bin subdirectory of the VCS root in question.

The build log doesn't hint at there being any problems here:

**[11:43:46]: [Updating sources: server side checkout...] Building incremental patch for VCS root: website-static**

is all the log mentions.

Compiling doesn't have any problems, and only when the site, which is built on Umbraco, is browsed to, does the fact that **Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll** (amongst others) has not been retrieved come to light.

There are other Umbraco based sites already set up on this server that are not experiencing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be going on, or at least where I could start looking?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the teamcity-vcs.log in Administration | Server Configuration | Server Logs, if any error or warning occurs during the checkout.

Comment: Just an other attempt: Perhaps the code diffs aren't determined correctly. Did you try to select "Clean all files before build: " in the "Version Control Settings"-section in your project configuration?

Comment: Kim, thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, there are no errors showing in the log and selecting "Clean all..." made no difference. Certain DLLs are still simply not being copied from the repo. Are there any other suggestions out there?

Comment: I am having the same problem. It seems to affect only files that have more than one period, such as Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll or, annoyingly, MyCompany.foo.bar.sln.  Running an svn checkout from the command-line on the same build server, as the same user, checks out fine.  the only changes I've made to TeamCity was to upgrade from the Professional to the Enterprise licence, and the build affected is the first one over the 20 build configuration limit.  Correlations, of course, but it's all I have to go on.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you have to kick it to make it run. :-) When we experience this type of behaviour, we select "Enforce clean checkout" in the build configuration view, and then press Run again.

[image]

Comment: Niklas, thanks for your suggestion. I gave it a go, but ended up in the exact same place. Certain DLLs were simply not brought over from subversion. Seeing as these are static DLLs, not expected to ever change, I've just copied them manually, and added it to the documentation for this site.

Comment: This is very strange... What happens if you do a manual svn checkout on the buildserver? Not through TeamCity that is?

Comment: This worked fine. I've eventually had to bite the bullet and document this little bit of weirdness. Fortunately, it's only happening with static libraries on a single site. It's not perfect, but we can live with it.

Comment: So it worked in TeamCity eventually? Or only with a manual checkout? (Sorry if I'm daft...)

Comment: It worked with manual check-out. The amount of time spent trying to figure out what was happening was getting excessive - many manual check-outs could have been done in that time. And with it being static files, rather than those that are changed or built by the agent, it just seemed best to let it go.

Answer (score 3):

In my case(team city server 8.0.3) we had a strange situation when team city didn't update part of external svn folder. Based on release note of 8.0.4 server there was issue, related with externals work: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-31507, but upgrade to new server didn't help too.

The solution was the switching of external setting for VCS root from "Full support (load changes and checkout)" to  "Checkout, but ignore changes". After it our external folder was updated correctly.

Hope this help to resolve such kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If there are checkout rules in the VCS Root under Version Control settings for your configuration, they maybe selectively checking out only certain parts of the root which did not include `/website/bin`

Can you do a clean of the checkout and try it again? It is done from the Version Control settings:

[image]

Comment: There are no checkout rules configured for this root, but I'll give Kim's suggestions a go and get back to you all.

Comment: Tried this, did not work :( This one is assigned to the Vault of Inexplicable Weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of looking bad for answering my own question here, I'm going to have to say there was no answer to this strangeness. Eventually, I gave up, as it was taking too much time to be justified for such a small, if perplexing, issue.
The workaround has proved to be a manual check out when required.